# After image resize transparency is removed - gdi+

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

I am reading an image from file that contains transparency area in the center (frame image type).

```
 Image myFrame = Image.FromFile("d:\mypngfile.png");
```

After i call image resize custome function:

```
myFrame = resizeImage(myFrame, new Size(otherbmp.Width, otherbmp.Height));
```

The problem is that after reszing the image it seems transparency  is removed.

**resize function:**

```
 public Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
    {
        int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;
        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;
        nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);
        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            nPercent = nPercentH;
        else
            nPercent = nPercentW;
        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        b.MakeTransparent();
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);
        g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
        g.Dispose();
        return (Image)b;
    }
```

After i am checking the alpha pixels which doesn't work after resize (**it does work before resizing and returns a value**). It always return 0!

```
  public int GetBorderWidth(Bitmap bmp)
            {
                var hy = bmp.Height/ 2;


                while (bmp.GetPixel(0, hy).A == 255 && sz.Width < hx)
                    sz.Width++;

                 return sz.width;
             }
```

I can't seem to solve this issue no matter what i try...

Comment: Calling `MakeTransparent(Color.Transparent)` 5 times should be a hint that you are not using it correctly.

Comment: Was for testing pourposes ..edited- removed 4 of them.. still same result ... What do you suggest?

Comment: You probably dont want to call it at all. Edit: And create the target Bitmap with `Format32bppArgb`.

Comment: I removed them. but how do i create the target Bitmap with Format32bppArgb?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z132tat(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I modifed line to:   Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb); in the resize function. still same result..

Comment: Also try `CompositingMode.SourceOver`

Comment: tried.. same result :(

Comment: *after resizing the image it seems transparency is removed* - You test very it *strangely*. Using `Size` to hold `x`. Are you sure logic is correct and it does what it should do? Did you try to search for *any* transparent pixel in resized image?

Comment: I think the function: GetBorderWidth that checks the bmp.GetPixel(sz.Width, hy).A == 255  does the transparency test.

Comment: PNG has 3 distinct ways to specify transparency.  You'll have to tell us more about the source image, a link to the file would be wise.

Comment: the issue is that the function GetBorderWidth works for the png image if i DO NOT resize it with the resize function. here is a link to the image: http://picpaste.com/4-yW8GP5cY.png

Comment: If there is transparency only in the middle of your image, i makes little sense to run your (dubious) test only along the top border line..

Comment: i fixed that function it in the question,  but still same result. my error didn't copy/paste it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it was related that after resizing the image it seems that the border has some transparent pixels ..(like Alpha 150) so the border was not ALPHA 255..
What i did i changed the function GetBorderWidth code with

> while (bmp.GetPixel(sz.Width, hy).A > 10 && sz.Width < hx)
>                   sz.Width++;

and it seems it fixed the issue.
thank you all for giving me some idea of what to check.